# How to pass a string from one method to the Main method?

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass a string from one method to my `Main` method.

The program is a C# console application. It is supposed to have the user input his first name, last name and birth place. Then it should reverse each of those and output them again. (e.g. Bob Tabor America -> boB robaT aciremA).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelperMethods
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetString();
            DisplayResult(ReverseString(input));
        }
        private static string GetString()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Name Game");

            Console.Write("What's your first name? ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("What's your last name? ");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("In what city were you born? ");
            string birthPlace = Console.ReadLine();

            string input = firstName + " " + lastName + " " + birthPlace;
            return input;
        }

        private static string ReverseString(string message)
        {
            char[] messageArray = message.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(messageArray);
            return String.Concat(messageArray);
        }

        private static void DisplayResult(string result)
        {
            Console.Write("Results: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Note how I am trying to pass the string input from `GetString()` to the `Main` method.

The given error is this:

> The name 'input' does not exist in the current context

What should I do?

Comment: Capture the *return* value: `string input = GetString();` (or `ReverseString(GetString())`)

Comment: Note that if you reverse First+Last+Place the string will begin with the reversed Place which is not what you want ... Reverse each individually then concatenate them together.

Comment: @AlexK. You're right, thank you. How would i pass the three strings (firstName, lastName and birthPlace) from GetString() to Main? I tried return firstName; return lastName; return birthPlace; , but that didn't work.

Comment: Change `GetString()` to `string input = Reverse(firstName) + " " + Reverse(lastName) + " " + Reverse(birthPlace);` then just `DisplayResult(input);` in `main()`.

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string input = GetString();
   DisplayResult(ReverseString(input));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `input` first:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var input = GetString();
     DisplayResult(ReverseString(input));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace HelperMethods
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = GetString();
            DisplayResult(ReverseString(input));

        }

        private static string GetString()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Name Game");

            Console.Write("What's your first name? ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("What's your last name? ");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("In what city were you born? ");
            string birthPlace = Console.ReadLine();

            string input = firstName + " " + lastName + " " + birthPlace;
            return input;
        }


        private static string ReverseString(string message)
        {
            char[] messageArray = message.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(messageArray);
            return String.Concat(messageArray);
        }

        private static void DisplayResult(string result)
        {
            Console.Write("Results: " + result);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = GetString();
DisplayResult(ReverseString(result));
```

Comment: Hi vscorp1991; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: @VinceBowdren 
You are right, Vince. Everything comes with experience, even answers on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DisplayResult(ReverseString(GetString()));
}
```

However, for the output that you expect, reverse every word before print/concat.

For example

```
using System;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("The Name Game");
        Console.Write("What's your first name? ");
        var firstName = Console.ReadLine().Reverse();
        Console.Write("What's your last name? ");
        var lastName = Console.ReadLine().Reverse();
        Console.Write("In what city were you born? ");
        var birthPlace = Console.ReadLine().Reverse();
        Console.Write("Result: {0} {1} {2}", firstName, lastName, birthPlace);
    }

    public static string Reverse(this string s) {
        var arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string (arr);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Result: boB robaT aciremA
```

Comment: That's great! I have some questions about that code that would further my learning of C#, if you don't mind? 1. Why did you use "this" in the name of the second method? 2. Why did you do "return new string (arr);" and not "return arr;". Obviously you're right (mine returns an error), but I don't understand why.

Comment: @JoeThorpe in regards to your second question: The return type of `Reverse()` is of type `string` (seen by `public static **string** Reverse()`, meaning you can't return anything else other than a `string`. `return new string (arr)` is creating a string out of the sequential characters in the `char array`.

Comment: @JoeThorpe `this` represents an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx).